# How do I get a subprocess to suspend execution of an external program every 5 seconds?

Tags: python, signals, subprocess

Given an external program, which for this example is `python target.py`:

### target.py

```
import time, itertools
A = itertools.count()
while True:
    time.sleep(.1)
    print A.next()
```

I'm looking for a way to run the command, which we can assume I have no control over other than starting and stopping, for 5 seconds. At that point, I'd like to suspend execution (similar to `control-Z` on linux, which is my target platform), run some internal code then continue the execution of the subprocess. So far I've got

### reader.py

```
import subprocess, signal, time

cmd = "python target.py"
P = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)

while True:
   time.sleep(5)
   signal.pause(P)  # Not the correct way to suspend P
   print "doing something"
   signal.wakeup(P) # What is called here?
```

Comment: @MichaelHerrmann It's buried in question, but this needs to work on a Linux machine (specifically Ubuntu, though I'm not sure that makes a difference).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see. My answer below :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are on Linux, you can use the following reader.py:

```
import subprocess, signal, time, os

cmd = "python target.py"
P = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)

while True:
   time.sleep(5)
   os.kill(P.pid, signal.SIGSTOP)
   print "doing something"
   os.kill(P.pid, signal.SIGCONT)
```

Comment: Thanks that does it! But wtf, the command to send a signal to a process is under `os.kill`?

Comment: Just a note, some commands like mpg123 can't be stopped if they are opened with the parameter `shell=True`. use `subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', 'audio.mp3'])` instead.

Comment: it now says signal doesnt have SIGSTOP or SIGCONT attributes

Answer (score 15):

You can also use psutil and avoid the scary-looking os.kill:

```
import psutil, time, subprocess

cmd = "python target.py"
P = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
psProcess = psutil.Process(pid=P.pid)

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    psProcess.suspend()
    print 'I am proactively leveraging my synergies!'
    psProcess.resume()
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use the `send_signal` function of subprocess

```
import subprocess
import signal
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', '-C', 'music.mp3'])
time.sleep(3)
print('stop')
p.send_signal(signal.SIGSTOP)
time.sleep(3)
print('continue')
p.send_signal(signal.SIGCONT)
time.sleep(3)
p.terminate()
```