# How to pause/resume ongoing ffmpeg rtmp stream via python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I have downloaded an audio file and I am streaming it on my client, What I want is when the user click pause button I want to pause the music and similarly resume it, how can I do so via ffmpeg? I am making commands via python and subprocess module to stream the music on my client. Also I have many users at same time and I want to only pause the music which the user requested, I am streaming the music via:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("""ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i "video.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ac 1 -f flv rtmps://dc1-1.rtmp.t.me/s/10909994:xxxxx""")
```

I dont know a better approach than running subprocess, is there any good workaround to serve different audios to many users at once?

Comment: The [following post](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17061/is-there-a-way-to-pause-and-resume-ffmpeg-encoding) details few alternatives.

Comment: For Python, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984666) could be helpful (I've wondered the same in the past, but never tried this solution myself)

Comment: @kesh sadly, I have tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984666) and this dont work, :(, aint there any way to do it directly via ffmpeg command?

Comment: Have you looked into `pyav`? It's a wrapper of `libav` shared library behind `ffmpeg` and I think you will be able to have finer control over media streams